# Phaser applying physics to child class of Phaser.Sprite (ES6)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to apply Gravity.Y Arcade Physics to a Character Class(Phaser.Sprite). But gravity.y did not affect the Sprite and remained in its position.

Is there any specific order to apply the physics?
NOTE: I have also tried to enable/apply physics before and after game.add.existing(char)

**1) Failed**

An example of the extended Phaser.Sprite Character class,

which has applied ARCADE physics, but it's not functioning:

```
class Char extend Phaser.Sprite {
     constructor(game,x,y){
        super(game,x,y,'dude')
        game.add.existing(this)
        game.physics.arcade.enable(this)
        this.body.gravity.y = 300
     }
}

// calling it in create()
create(game){
   game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE)

   var x = new Char(game,0,0)

}
```

**2) Working**

And then tried the normal Sprite creation and the gravity.y works...

```
create(game){
   game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE)

   var x = game.add.sprite(0,0,'dude')
   game.physics.arcade.enable(x)
   x.body.gravity.y=300
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad

The code is actually working,
it was due to another setting "fixedToCamera = true"